# Unable to complete TFTP transfer via SCCM PXE boot

Tags: pxe, tftp, sccm, windows-server-2019

I'm new to SCCM and have been setting it up in a dev environment available to me. Every machine is virtual and is isolated on its own VLAN (servers and clients alike).

When I try to PXE boot any machine (BIOS or UEFI), initially the TFTP transfer seems to be going well, until usually a few seconds in when I get this error screen:

[image: I get this error screen]]

After some time looking at logs and confirming the server was finding a collection for the device in question, I ran a wireshark capture in case that showed anything. Each time the transfer fails, its on a different packet but they all have this one thing in common:

[image: this one thing in common:]]

1. The client sends two acknowledgements
2. The server attempts to send the next packet
3. An error is thrown to the client
4. A number of acknowledgements are made for the new packet by the client that the server does not respond to.
5. The client stops sending acknowledgements and shows the error screen I linked earlier

The following files are always successful: wdsnbp.com, pxeboot.com, bootmgr.exe, boot.bcd, wgl4_boot.ttf, boot.sdi. The error always occurs when transferring my actual boot.wim file, but only after quite a few packets were successfully sent/received.

Anyone have any thoughts on why I could be running into an issue like this?

SCCM Current Branch, Windows Server 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the July patches are responsible for this issue. Mitigation can be found here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4512816/devices-that-start-up-using-preboot-execution-environment-pxe-images-f

Personally, using the PXE Responder instead of WDS worked best for me.